# How to use Pandas in Python to concatenate similar multiple rows while putting differences in columns?

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, data-manipulation

I managed to query the below data I need using PostgreSQL.

```
Name    InstitutionID   Degree      GPA     CompanyID   PositionID  Duration    Rating
Alex    10              Bachelor    3.33    123         8           24          Good
Alex    13              Master      3.57    123         8           24          Good
Alex    17              Doctorate   3.91    123         8           24          Good
Alex    10              Bachelor    3.33    101         12          48          Good
Alex    13              Master      3.57    101         12          48          Good
Alex    17              Doctorate   3.91    101         12          48          Good
Bob     12              Bachelor    3.25    197         6           12          Bad
Bob     17              Master      3.66    197         6           12          Bad
Bob     12              Bachelor    3.25    218         9           36          Bad
Bob     17              Master      3.66    218         9           36          Bad
```

But would need to do slight manipulation to get it into a matrix as shown on the second table which shows 0 for names that does not have that column. Rows are unique to the names.

I have attempted using the code below but it did not give the desired output but instead dummy variables. The dummy variables are good for indicating presence of values but it would be more desirable to have those values immediately placed.

```py
pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.Degree)], 1).groupby(['Name','Rating']).sum().reset_index()
```

Desired Result

```
Name    InstitutionID1  Degree1     GPA1    InstitutionID2  Degree2     GPA2    InstitutionID3  Degree3     GPA3    CompanyID1  PositionID1     Duration1   CompanyID2  PositionID2     Duration2   CompanyID3  PositionID3     Duration3   Rating
Alex    10              Bachelor    3.33    13              Master      3.57    17              Doctorate   3.91    123         8               24          101         12              48          0           0               0           Good
Bob     12              Bachelor    3.25    17              Master      3.66    0               0           0       197         6               12          218         9               36          0           0               0           Bad
```

Comment: What is your desired result? Even more, why do you want that wide format?

Comment: Would like to have a cleaned dataset that focuses on each unique individual's achievements.

Comment: Original long format would be the cleaner dataset. Why not just build a list of dataframes for each individual? Right now you have different number of matches such as 3 *Institutions/Degree/Grade*, 2 *Company/Position*, and 1 *Rating*  that you lose which goes with which. I advise sticking to original long format. All your analysis needs, `groupby`, `pivot_table`, `crosstab`, `plot` works best this way.